# Facebook Business Verification - UK based freelancer

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager

A wild adventurer trying to create an app for Facebook here! I tried asking this question in the meta developer forums but those seem to be *quite abandoned*... I feel that this is more of a law / business related question, but I'm hoping someone here has faced/solved a similar issue...!

**The Problem**

I am a freelance software developer in the UK. I have developed an app to automatically retreive some data for one of my client's Facebook Page - which until now they retrieved manually. While it is a simple app, it does ask for some data that is only given to Business Verified apps. I'd like to verify it but, as a freelancer, I do not have a business registered - just to clarify, in case it works different elsewehre, this is not ilegal. I am registered as a freelancer and pay tax, but in the UK this does not mean registering as a business.

**The Possible Solution**

After giving it some thought, the only solution that I can find to this is to register a new business and leave it dormant. I am not going to trade with that business, as it would be created just for the sake of this app - which I want to leave open for anyone to use with no cost. According to [gov.uk Corporation Tax page](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gov.uk%2Fguidance%2Fcorporation-tax-trading-and-non-trading%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR3FIHfraJc8vPoDKd7tmYJ9WoPfqJFiQnv5Ro7E-z5xaJChBMl0X1rg-tg&h=AT27q14QxQcvYO2F_mjZ7Um224MmtdH6yUD2ZRvUReysVB52FlRrf9TyJE1Q8Nnz8LTcfxXwewoi-IHYLiyvqW1B4vtpfECyGNKaMNf5L01k--728sAl7YeP9w22pMHrQ5NUGQ), as long as a business is not trading it is considered dormant and therefore you shouldn't pay any tax. At the same time, it seems that I'd still have to do some [annual paperwork](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gov.uk%2Fdormant-company%2Fdormant-for-companies-house%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR28JjxgmYpKEODID2ZLOjwpM618UY-gFRK0F-CzmlwcrCrd5jU_lZCOeso&h=AT27q14QxQcvYO2F_mjZ7Um224MmtdH6yUD2ZRvUReysVB52FlRrf9TyJE1Q8Nnz8LTcfxXwewoi-IHYLiyvqW1B4vtpfECyGNKaMNf5L01k--728sAl7YeP9w22pMHrQ5NUGQ) which is not ideal.

**The Question(s)**

Has anyone done this? Could this become too complicated for what I am trying to achieve?